# unresolved dependency org.mongodb#bson#2.5, bad organisation in sbt

Tags: java, scala, playframework, sbt, bson

I'm trying to use `"org.apache.mahout" % "mahout-integration" % "0.7"` as a dependency inside my play2 based web application.

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.mongodb#bson;2.5: java.text.ParseException: inconsistent module descriptor file found in 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/bson/2.5/bson-2.5.pom': bad organisation: expected='org.mongodb' found='org.bson';
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.mongodb#bson;2.5: java.text.ParseException: inconsistent module descriptor file found in 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/bson/2.5/bson-2.5.pom': bad organisation: expected='org.mongodb' found='org.bson';
    at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:214)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:122)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:121)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:114)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:114)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:102)
    at sbt.IvySbt.liftedTree1$1(Ivy.scala:49)
    at sbt.IvySbt.action$1(Ivy.scala:49)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:58)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:75)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:58)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:79)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:11)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.liftedTree1$1(Locks.scala:51)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:51)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:30)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:27)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:58)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:99)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:95)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:114)
    at sbt.IvyActions$.update(IvyActions.scala:121)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:951)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:949)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$54.apply(Defaults.scala:972)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$54.apply(Defaults.scala:970)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:35)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:974)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:969)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:45)
    at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:977)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$45.apply(Defaults.scala:856)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$45.apply(Defaults.scala:853)
    at sbt.Scoped$$anonfun$hf10$1.apply(Structure.scala:586)
    at sbt.Scoped$$anonfun$hf10$1.apply(Structure.scala:586)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:49)
    at sbt.Scoped$Reduced$$anonfun$combine$1$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(Structure.scala:311)
    at sbt.Scoped$Reduced$$anonfun$combine$1$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(Structure.scala:311)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:41)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$5.work(System.scala:71)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:238)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.mongodb#bson;2.5: java.text.ParseException: inconsistent module descriptor file found in 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/bson/2.5/bson-2.5.pom': bad organisation: expected='org.mongodb' found='org.bson';
[error] Total time: 15 s, completed 20 May 2013 13:00:08
```

Is it possible to workaround that issue with `externalPom()` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

my workaround:

```
"org.apache.mahout" % "mahout-integration" % "0.7" exclude("org.mongodb", "bson"),
"org.mongodb" % "bson" % "2.5" from "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/bson/2.5/bson-2.5.jar",
```

But of course the bug should be fixed in `bson.pom` (`groupId` should be `org.mongodb`) or repository layout (`bson.jar` have to be moved into `org/bson` dir).

P.S. http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/bson/2.11.1/bson-2.11.1.pom contains correct `groupId`.