# sbt inconsistent module descriptor file found

Tags: sbt

I have some errors in sbt:

```
[error] (system/*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.ant#ant-compress;1.4: java.text.ParseException: inconsistent module descriptor file found in 'http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ant/ant-compress/1.4/ant-compress-1.4.pom': bad module name: expected='ant-compress' found='compress-antlib';
```

the artifact id of [ant-compress](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ant/ant-compress/1.4/ant-compress-1.4.pom) not same as the module name

how can i figure out this?

does sbt has some configuration to suppress the consistency check?

I have using the method refer to [unresolved dependency org.mongodb#bson#2.5, bad organisation in sbt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16647840/unresolved-dependency-org-mongodbbson2-5-bad-organisation-in-sbt)

```
"com.example.utils" % "example-lang" % "0.0.3-SNAPSHOT" exclude("org.apache.ant", "ant-compress"),
"org.apache.ant" % "ant-compress" % "1.4" from "http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ant/ant-compress/1.4/ant-compress-1.4.jar",
```

but some other errors occured:

```
[error] (system/*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.ant#ant-compress;1.4: configuration not found in org.apache.ant#ant-compress;1.4: 'master(compile)'. Missing configuration: 'comp
ile'. It was required from com.example.utils#example-lang;0.0.2-SNAPSHOT runtime
```